# cv::imread() fails in c++ project when we mix opencv and dlib

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

I have a c++ project created in visual studio 2019. I compiled and build openCV version 4.2.0 and dlib version 19.19.0 and used in my c++ project. My motto using opencv and dlib in single project is I want to do face detection using opencv's DNN (caffe) and dlib's hog + svm based face detector (get_frontal_face_detector()).

My both functions are separate, i.e `detectFaceByOpenCVDNN()` for opencv based face detection and `detectFaceBydlibHOG()` for dlib based HOG + SVM based detector.

I added include directory of both projects, lib directories (additional library directories) and mentioned additional dependencies with .lib files.

Build of this project is successful and generates .lib file. By using this file another c++ console application calls for `detectFaceByOpenCVDNN()` (opencv face detector).

Code of `detectFaceByOpenCVDNN()`:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp>

#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv::dnn;

void namespace_name::FaceDetection::detectFaceByOpenCVDNN(std::string filename)
{    

Net net;        
cv::Mat frame = cv::imread(filename);

if (frame.empty())
    throw std::exception("provided image file is not found or unable to open.");

int frameHeight = frame.rows;
int frameWidth = frame.cols;
    .... // code continues
}
```

When I this function, I receive exception as "provided image file is not found or unable to open." which is throw if `frame.empty()` return true. No other exception is displayed on console.

While just digging what makes this fail, I got to know that, If I remove `dlib19.19.0_debug_32bit_msvc1924.lib` entry from Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies then `frame.empty()` returns false and program continues.

But I still not get, why cv::imread() fails when I use opencv and dlib in single c++ project?

Comment: One more observation, Even if I remove every code related to dlib (detectFaceBydlibHOG(), #include entries, using statements) then also cv::imread() fails. As soon as I remove entry of `dlib19.19.0_debug_32bit_msvc1924.lib` from Additional Dependencies program reads image.

Comment: So when you just run the code only by using *imread* without *dlib*, does it work properly?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, Yes. As I said in my first comment. When I remove dlib's .lib entry from "Additional Dependencies" `imread()` works as expected.

Comment: Did you build dlib with libjpeg and libpng build statically into it?  It’s probably conflicting with a similar copy of those libraries statically build into your opencv .lib file. Just rebuild dlib without that if you aren’t using those libraries.

Comment: Or link both opencv and dlib to the same libjpeg and libpng libraries.

Comment: @DavisKing _Did you build dlib with libjpeg and libpng build statically into it?_ In openCV's lib folder I can see `libjpeg-turbod.lib` file but in Dlib's lib folder I can only see `dlib19.19.0_debug_32bit_msvc1924.lib` file. Is that mean Dlib build without libjpeg?

Comment: @DavisKing In Cmake DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT is on. I am building Dlib again after making it off.

Comment: @DavisKing, Bingo!!! :) Man you are just awesome. As you said it's due to conflict between libjpeg. OpenCV is already build with libjpeg and it's lib is already added in Additional Dependencies, then, when I build dlib I kept `DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT` on which default so dlib also build statically with libjpeg and hence conflict happens. Thanks Man!! I don't think without this help, I am alone, I could able to track down it.

Comment: Ha, no problem   :)

Comment: @DavisKing Please update as answer and give me pleasure to appreciate you :). I (we) would like to read exact cause of this from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you build dlib with libjpeg and libpng build statically into it? It’s probably conflicting with a similar copy of those libraries statically build into your opencv .lib file. Just rebuild dlib without that if you aren’t using those libraries.

Or link both opencv and dlib to the same libjpeg and libpng libraries.

Dlib's cmake files will try to link with libjpeg and libpng, and if they can't find a system copy will build and statically link the copy in dlib/external.  You can control if cmake will attempt to link to these things by setting `DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT` and `DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT`

Comment: Can we link DLib with OpenCV's LIBJPEG static lib? Our should we just build DLib without DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT and expect it to link against OpenCV's LIBJPEG? Thanks.